# Why can't I use the font I have?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

In my css code I use the @font-face to acces my font. I have this:

```
  @font-face {
   font-family: codec;
   src: url(Codec-Cold-Regular-trial.woff);
}
```

I tried it with and without the format tag at the end but it isn't working. One thing I noticed was that the 'src' tag looks different then all the other tags in my css (I use notepad++). This is how I use my font in the css:

```
body {
background-image:url('background.jpg');
background-size:cover;
height:100%;
font-family:mainFont;
```

}

I think it has something to do with not seeing the src tag to get the code.
Also, I'm 100% sure the file path and the name of the font is correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `font-family: codec;` and `font-family:mainFont;` are different

Comment: "the format tag at the end" — What "format tag"?

Comment: "I think it has something to do with not seeing the src tag to get the code" — Have you checked the Network tab to see if the request is being made and if it gets a response?

Comment: Whoops, the difference in font-family was because I tried to see if it worked if I changed the name. Unfortunately, even when the names are the same it still doesn't work. For your second point, when I googled about the @font-face, I saw some people do it like this: `   src: url(Codec-Cold-Regular-trial.woff) format("woff"); ` Don't know if this matters. For your third point, how and where do I check the network tab? Not sure if this matters, but this html and css file are locally saved and not hosted.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Comment: You will usually need many more font files. `woff` is just one of them. You could bash it through Font Sq? https://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: "but this html and css file are locally saved and not hosted" — I wouldn't be surprised if there was a cross-origin error reported in the Console then

Comment: @David – `woff` is [well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) across browsers. There's probably no need for any other format.

Comment: @Quentin probably true

Comment: Just thought of this: maybe it has something to do with the fact that I already have another font stylesheet for icons? In the <head> of my HTML file i have this line: ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css"> `. Could that maybe cause interference with the other font?